# R indentation in Google's R Style Guide

Tags: r, rstudio

I am reading [Google's R Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml). It said:

> When indenting your code, use two spaces. Never use tabs or mix tabs and spaces.

I use R Studio to program and feel it is very convenient and beautiful to use tabs. Other programming languages also use tabs for indentation.

I don't know why Google's R Style Guide does not recommend use tabs but two blanks.

Comment: So don't follow it.  Problem solved.  This seems to be quite off-topic.

Comment: because spaces have the same length on all devices, not tabs. So what looks nice on your own computer/monitor will likely look awful (misaligned) the minute you try to share your code with somebody else.

Answer (score 4):

You will notice if you check the options in `Rstudio` under `code editing` there is a choice for replacing `tabs` with a defined number of spaces. If you select this (which is set as default, with width = 2), then your tabs will be replaced automatically.